# Have the Chinese Been Behind Any Terrorist Attack in the United States?

Tags: united-states, china, terrorism

[Chinese leaders encourage using "terrorism" against the US](https://www.theepochtimes.com/chinese-general-says-contain-the-united-states-by-attacking-its-finances_1967150.html), as one tool of containing the US:

> In “Unrestricted Warfare,” Qiao and Wang promoted the use of terrorism, cyberattacks, legal warfare (also called “lawfare”), and economic warfare against the United States.

The [book was written in 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_Warfare) before September 11th, 2001 and any of the other later attacks in the country.  Have any of the terrorist attacks in the US been found to have any Chinese support, whether direct financial, indirect training or other methods?

Comment: [That book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_Warfare#Source_of_text) is written by two colonels regarding how *any* nation could theoretically fight against a superior foe by avoiding a direct fight, *not* "here are tactics Chinese leaders promote for use against the US". It's a book of recommendations, not policy.

Comment: Cyberattacks blamed on China, Chinese companies are involved in legal action especially over intellectual property, concern about how China manages international markets is very common in US news. Or are you just interested in the kind of terrorism where people die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in China, everything is state controlled. There have been numerous reports regarding government sponsored cyber attacks by China, throughout the world. But time and again China have been denying their role in these attacks.(refer link : https://www.realcleardefense.com/articles/2017/11/23/chinese_state_sponsored_hacking_112675.html).
Also China have notoriously supported Pakistani terrorist (offically declared as global terrorist by the US), refer links :

1. https://www.hindustantimes.com/opinion/pak-sponsored-terrorists-with-chinese-weapons-making-counter-insurgency-in-kashmir-bloodier/story-MkIMDPSNSG4nReucYMa0KK.html
2. http://www.dw.com/en/why-is-china-protecting-the-pakistan-based-jaish-e-mohammad-militant-group/a-36974181
3. http://www.defencenews.in/article/After-repeatedly-protecting-Hafiz-Saeed,-China-now-blocks-Interpol-Red-Notice-against-Zakir-Naik-515132

All these are happening even though China themselves are facing such attacks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_in_China)

Comment: The question does look for US targets.